# When the verb agrees with the object, like in "es sind"?

Tags: verb

I came across the following sentence [in Duolingo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/11112814):

> Im Moment **sind** *es* zehn Grad.

It is quite surprising that the verb agrees with the object, not the subject. What is the generic rule defining when the verb agrees by an object?

Answer (score 1):

The generic rule that the verb needs to agree with an object is: The verb needs to comply with the object - always.

You could argue *es* to be plural in this case (there is no specific plural for this word). When used as a predicative noun, *es* relates as a placeholder for a pronoun or noun in singular or plural.

Comment: *Zehn Grad* is not an object here but a *predicative*. It's in nominative case, unlike true objects.

Comment: @RHa Which wasn't the question. The question is about plural. I think your comment should go below the question, not my answer (because that's where "object" was stated)